# PHP remove spaces from string but from in between numbers only

Tags: php, regex, string

My input is

```
07786 000 000 Marie Claire
```

My desired output is

```
07786000000 Marie Claire
```

Basically, I want to remove the spaces from in between the numbers only.

My attempt so far removes all spaces

```
$phone_number = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $phone_number);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use lookarounds

```
(?<=\d)\s+(?=\d)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/ePKk5P/1/).

---

In `PHP`:

```
$regex = "~(?<=\d)\s+(?=\d)~";
$phone_number = preg_replace($regex, '', $phone_number);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option using `preg_replace`:

```
$input = "07786 000 000 Marie Claire";
$output = preg_replace("/(\d)\s+(\d)/", "$1$2", $input);
echo $input . "\n" . $output;
```

This prints:

```
07786 000 000 Marie Claire
07786000000 Marie Claire
```